# How to upload file for multiple file inputs

Tags: javascript

I have multiple `<input type="file name="uploadx">`. Is there any way I can automate file uploads during testing stage instead of upload them one by one?

Comment: Why don't you use `multiple` attribute in your `input` tag? like this. `<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>`'

Comment: To differentiate purpose of each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is for automation, as far as i know, that's not gonna be a easy task by just using the vanilla Javascript. You'll need a tool for the automation process. Any how, if you don't want to select and upload each file one by one. There is an attribute **'multiple'** that you can use in file element to select all the files at once and upload them.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

Comment: I need to test multiple file <input> instead of uploading multiple files at once. Thanks